# Calling a custom web API secured with Azure AD from SharePoint 2019 on-premise

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, graph-api

I need to call custom web APIs secured with Azure AD from my SharePoint 2019 on-premise SharePoint Framework solutions. As far as I know, this scenario and calling graph APIs are only supported in SharePoint Online.

I was following the [article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/guidance/connect-to-api-secured-with-aad). It has mentioned to add `webApiPermissionRequests` key in package-solution.js. But, after adding the *webApiPermissionRequests* key, package failed to deploy in app catalog with error "Error in the application".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On-prem SharePoint uses SPFx 1.4.1, so you cannot use *AadTokenProvider*, meaning you need to use ADAL JS, see instructions [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).

`webApiPermissionRequests` refers to *AadTokenProvider* which in turn requires SPFx 1.6.0+, thus is not currently supported on on-prem SP.